# Why is my website not getting PageRank updates?

Tags: seo, google, google-search, pagerank

My website is more than a year old and Google Webmaster Tools reports that I have over 1500 links to the site, yet my Google PageRank is still zero.

Is my website being penalised and why is my PageRank not updating?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google PageRank has not been updated for a while (since 4 February 2013) and [probably won't be updated anymore](http://searchengineland.com/googles-matt-cutts-no-more-pagerank-updates-this-year-173676).

Moreover, it's not because the website has not a PageRank updated than it's penalized. Anyway, I checked and the website is not penalized.

If I were you, I should forget this PageRank concept. Nowadays, it's not accurate anymore.

Comment: Any software tool, techniques, tips you suggest, to improve search engine ranking. I have kind of done my best but still results are not good. Its disappointing but don't want to give up! Will appreciate any tips and help website URL is: innovativetxt.com

Comment: The site looks good SEO optimized, try to review [basis factors](http://www.searchenginejournal.com/infographic-googles-200-ranking-factors/) to see if you can get any idea.

Answer (score -1):

Regular blog update with high quality & unique content can improve your site Pagerank.

Comment: Whilst this can certainly help your page rank in the search engines, the concept of "PageRank" itself (a ranking signal used by Google based on the number and quality of inbound links) is an outdated concept.